# Issue installing fresh version of windows 10

Tags: windows-10

I tried to clone my previous HDD to an SSD to replace it but the HDD died somehow while doing it. Now, I'm trying to install windows 10 iso from a 16Gb usb drive burnt with rufus to the SSD.

Laptop is now complaining about not finding a boot device. This laptop came with uefi and ever since the HDD died, I haven't been able to see the uefi menu to select usb as boot device. Was the uefi in the HDD? If so, how can I install windows without one since it is lost>

Comment: More info would be helpful, e.g. "the HDD died somehow?"

Comment: Yes, it died while cloning. I cannot access any data from it and doesn't mount anymore. Tried it on 3 computers and nothing

Comment: First things first, UEFI is what replaces the 35 years old BIOS. Same purpose, enhanced functionality and hardware support. For all intended purposes though it works like the old BIOS and yes, it is there that you change the boot order.

Comment: Many computers have a key to press most HP are F9.  Maybe F2,F10, or DEL to change the boot order in the BIOS.  Try your USB stick in a USB 2.0 port first as some USB 3 ports need drivers not included in the windows ISO.

Comment: I was able to use ESC to get to the UEFI before HDD died but now it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

probably damaged master boot records. but anyway, use the win 10 media creation tool.
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10?tduid=(c3d23cd112f92f204835e1176d014dad)(259740)(2542549)(UUwpUdUnU50931YYw)(dwp)

Comment: I was looking for something like this from MS. If it works I'll accept your answer.

Comment: i've used it for at least two dozens bootable installers. never had an issue

Comment: It let me install great!

Comment: Here's a valuable lesson: Do not use third party tools (Rufus) if there's an official tool for the purpose. Use Rufus for making Linux live/installation media in Windows.

Comment: Glad i could help

Comment: @MichaelBay Rufus is fine.  You just have to use the correct setting for

Comment: @Ramhound I know ;), but still. There's an official tool, a Microsoft product you can complain of if things go south, unlike when using third party tools that Microsoft justifiably may argue they don't and can't support.

Comment: @MichaelBay, Rufus developer here. I will happily support Rufus users on StackOverflow or on the official [issue tracker](https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/issues). ;)

In this case, I would assert that OP probably created their drive in BIOS mode, rather than UEFI, which is why it wasn't listed under UEFI boot devices, but of course it's hard to tell without additional data.